# How to remove particular day column while displaying month data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have written a js code for removing 31st date column.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#search").click(function() {
    var e = document.getElementById("selMonth");
    var monthSelect = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    var tid = null;

    if(
      $(this).value() == '4'||
      $(this).value() == '6'||
      $(this).value() == '9'||    
      $(this).value() == '11'
    ) {
      $('#Production_monitor thead tr td').each(function (event) {
        tid = $(this).attr('id');

        if($(this).text() == '31'){
          $('#' + tid).remove();
        }
      });
    }

    if($(this).value() == '2') {
      $('#Production_monitor thead tr td').each(function (event) {
        tid = $(this).attr('id');

        if($(this).text() == '31'){
          $('#' + tid).remove();
        }

        if($(this).text() == '30'){
          $('#' + tid).remove();            
        }
      });
    }

    prodmonitor(monthSelect);
  });
});
```

And html code is like below.
I want to dynamically remove 31st date column whenever I need to display the data for April, June, September, November as well as remove the 31st and 30th column for month February.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<!-- Meta, title, CSS, favicons, etc. -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/ico" />

<title>HMSI</title>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="vendors/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link href="vendors/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- NProgress -->
<link href="vendors/nprogress/nprogress.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- iCheck -->
<link href="vendors/iCheck/skins/flat/green.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- bootstrap-progressbar -->
<link href="vendors/bootstrap-progressbar/css/
 bootstrap-progressbar-3.3.4.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- JQVMap -->
<link href="vendors/jqvmap/dist/jqvmap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- bootstrap-daterangepicker -->
<link href="vendors/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" 
 rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Datatables -->
<link href="vendors/datatables.net-bs/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" 
 rel="stylesheet">
<link href="vendors/datatables.net-bs/css/editor.dataTables.min.css" 
 rel="stylesheet">
<link href="vendors/datatables.net-buttons-bs/css/buttons.bootstrap.min.css" 
 rel="stylesheet">
<link href="vendors/datatables.net-fixedheader- 
 bs/css/fixedHeader.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="vendors/datatables.net-responsive- 
 bs/css/responsive.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="vendors/datatables.net-scroller- 
 bs/css/scroller.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<!-- Custom Theme Style -->
<link href="css/custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body class="nav-md">
<div class="container body">
  <div class="main_container">
    <div class="col-md-3 left_col">
      <div class="left_col scroll-view">
        <div class="navbar nav_title" style="border: 0;">
          <a href="index.jsp" class="site_title"><i class="fa fa-motorcycle"> 
</i> <span>HMSI</span></a>
        </div>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>

        <!-- menu profile quick info -->
        <div class="profile clearfix">
          <div class="profile_pic">
            <img src="images/img.jpg" alt="..."
             class="img-circle profile_img">
          </div>
          <div class="profile_info">
            <span>Welcome,</span>
            <h2>Admin</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /menu profile quick info -->

        <br />

        <!-- sidebar menu -->
        <div id="sidebar-menu" class="main_menu_side hidden-print main_menu">
          <div class="menu_section">
            <h3>General</h3>
            <ul class="nav side-menu">
              <li><a><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home <span class=
                      "fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                <ul class="nav child_menu">
                  <li><a href="Dashboard.jsp">Dashboard</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Associate <span class=
                      "fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                <ul class="nav child_menu">
                  <li><a href="Employee.jsp">All Employee</a></li>
                  <li><a href="Attendance.jsp">Attendance</a></li>
                  <li><a href="OT.jsp">OT</a></li>
                  <li><a href="Fingerprint.jsp">Finger Print</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Parameter </a>
              </li>

              <li><a><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i>Reports<span class=
                      "fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                <ul class="nav child_menu">
                    <li><a>Man Power<span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span> 
           </a>
                    <ul class="nav child_menu">
                        <li class="sub_menu">
                        <a href="Attendance.jsp">Attendance</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="OT_Monitor.jsp">OT Monitoring Sheet</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="Leave_Plan.jsp">Leave plan</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="Training_Plan.jsp">Training plan</a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a>Quality<span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span> 
                     </a>
                      <ul class="nav child_menu">
                        <li class="sub_menu"><a href="gdptrends.jsp">
                      GDP Trends</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="dpv_vs_actual.jsp">
                        DPV Targets vs Actual</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="pdiclaim.jsp">PDI Monitoring Sheet</a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a>Safety<span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                      <ul class="nav child_menu">
                        <li class="sub_menu">
                        <a href="Safety_Calender.jsp">Safety Calender</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="Safety_Message.jsp">Safety Message</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="audit_check.jsp">5s Check Sheet</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="risk_assesment.jsp">Risk Management</a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                     <li><a>Delivery<span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span> 
                      </a>
                      <ul class="nav child_menu">
                        <li class="sub_menu">
                   <a href="prod_monitor.jsp">Production Monitoring Sheet</a>
                        </li>
                         <li><a href="logistic_vs_pdi.jsp">
                          Login vs PDI OFF Monitoring Sheet</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="breakdown.jsp">Break Down Monitoring</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="holdstatus.jsp">Hold Vechicle</a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>

                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a><i class="fa fa-clone"></i>Layouts 
              <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                <ul class="nav child_menu">
                  <li><a href="fixed_sidebar.html">Fixed Sidebar</a></li>
                  <li><a href="fixed_footer.html">Fixed Footer</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="menu_section">
            <h3>Live On</h3>
            <ul class="nav side-menu">
              <li><a><i class="fa fa-bug"></i> Additional Pages 
              <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                <ul class="nav child_menu">
                  <li><a href="e_commerce.html">E-commerce</a></li>
                  <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
                  <li><a href="project_detail.html">Project Detail</a></li>
                  <li><a href="contacts.html">Contacts</a></li>
                  <li><a href="profile.html">Profile</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a><i class="fa fa-windows"></i> Extras 
              <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                <ul class="nav child_menu">
                  <li><a href="page_403.html">403 Error</a></li>
                  <li><a href="page_404.html">404 Error</a></li>
                  <li><a href="page_500.html">500 Error</a></li>
                  <li><a href="plain_page.html">Plain Page</a></li>
                  <li><a href="login.html">Login Page</a></li>
                  <li><a href="pricing_tables.html">Pricing Tables</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a><i class="fa fa-sitemap"></i> Multilevel Menu 
               <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                <ul class="nav child_menu">
                    <li><a href="#level1_1">Level One</a>
                    <li><a>Level One<span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span> 
                      </a>
                      <ul class="nav child_menu">
                        <li class="sub_menu"><a href="level2.html">
                       Level Two</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#level2_1">Level Two</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#level2_2">Level Two</a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#level1_2">Level One</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
              </li>                  
              <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fa fa-laptop"></i> 
             Landing Page <span class="label label-success pull-right">
             Coming Soon</span></a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>

        </div>
        <!-- /sidebar menu -->

        <!-- /menu footer buttons -->
        <div class="sidebar-footer hidden-small">
          <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Settings">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          </a>
          <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="FullScreen">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fullscreen" aria-hidden="true"> 
            </span>
          </a>
          <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Lock">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close" aria-hidden="true"> 
           </span>
          </a>
          <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" 
          title="Logout" href="login.html">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          </a>
        </div>
        <!-- /menu footer buttons -->
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- top navigation -->
    <div class="top_nav">
      <div class="nav_menu">
        <nav>
          <div class="nav toggle">
            <a id="menu_toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
          </div>

          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="">
              <a href="javascript:;" class="user-profile dropdown-toggle" 
               data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                <img src="images/img.jpg" alt="">Admin
                <span class=" fa fa-angle-down"></span>
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-usermenu pull-right">
                <li><a href="javascript:;"> Profile</a></li>
                <li>
                  <a href="javascript:;">
                    <span class="badge bg-red pull-right">50%</span>
                    <span>Settings</span>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="javascript:;">Help</a></li>
                <li><a href="login.html">
                <i class="fa fa-sign-out pull-right"></i> Log Out</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>

            <li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
              <a href="javascript:;" class="dropdown-toggle info-number" 
                   data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
                <span class="badge bg-green">6</span>
              </a>
              <ul id="menu1" class="dropdown-menu list-unstyled msg_list" 
               role="menu">
                <li>
                  <a>
                    <span class="image"><img src="images/img.jpg" 
                     alt="Profile Image" /></span>
                    <span>
                      <span>John Smith</span>
                      <span class="time">3 mins ago</span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="message">
                      Film festivals used to be do-or-die moments for movie 
                       makers. They were where...
                    </span>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a>
                    <span class="image"><img src="images/img.jpg" 
               alt="Profile Image" /></span>
                    <span>
                      <span>John Smith</span>
                      <span class="time">3 mins ago</span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="message">
                      Film festivals used to be do-or-die moments for movie 
                      makers. They were where...
                    </span>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a>
                    <span class="image"><img src="images/img.jpg" 
                     alt="Profile Image" /></span>
                    <span>
                      <span>John Smith</span>
                      <span class="time">3 mins ago</span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="message">
                      Film festivals used to be do-or-die moments for movie 
                        makers. They were where...
                    </span>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a>
                    <span class="image"><img src="images/img.jpg" 
                     alt="Profile Image" /></span>
                    <span>
                      <span>John Smith</span>
                      <span class="time">3 mins ago</span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="message">
                      Film festivals used to be do-or-die moments for movie 
                      makers. They were where...
                    </span>
                  </a >
                </li>
                <li>
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <a>
                      <strong>See All Alerts</strong>
                      <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>

   </div>
    <!-- /top navigation -->

    <!-- page content -->
     <div class="right_col" role="main">
    <!-- <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="x_panel">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
    <input type="search" class="form-control input-sm" 
        placeholder="Employee Id" aria-controls="datatable-fixed-header">
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
    <input type="search" class="form-control input-sm" 
        placeholder="Employee Name" aria-controls="datatable-fixed-header">
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
    <input type="search" class="form-control input-sm" 
       placeholder="Month" aria-controls="datatable-fixed-header">
     </div>
     <div id="dly_rpt_btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Clear 
     <i class="fa fa-eraser"></i></button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Print 
     <i class="fa fa-print"></i></button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Filter
    <i class="fa fa-filter"></i></button>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div> -->
    <div class=" form">
            <div class="field-wrap">    
            <h2>PRODUCTION MONITORING SHEET</h2>        
                     <select class="form-control" name="month" id="selMonth">
                        <option value="0">Select Month</option>
                        <option value="1">January</option>
                        <option value="2">February</option>
                        <option value="3">March</option>
                        <option value="4">April</option>
                        <option value="5">May</option>
                        <option value="6">June</option>
                        <option value="7">July</option>
                        <option value="8">August</option>
                        <option value="9">September</option>
                        <option value="10">October</option>
                        <option value="11">November</option>
                        <option value="12">December</option>
                    </select>     
                </div>

             <div class="field-wrap">
                <input type="submit" class="button button-block" 
                value="Search" id="search" />
            </div>  </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="x_panel">

              <div class="x_content">

                <div id="datatable-fixed-header_wrapper" 
               class="dataTables_wrapper form-inline dt-bootstrap no-footer">

                <div class="row">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                   <table class="table table-bordered jambo_table 
                         bulk_action" id="Production_monitor">
                    <thead>
                    <tr role="row">
                    <th class="column-title">Date</th>
                    <th class="column-title">1</th>
                    <th class="column-title">2</th>
                    <th class="column-title">3</th>
                    <th class="column-title">4</th>
                    <th class="column-title">5</th>
                    <th class="column-title">6</th>
                    <th class="column-title">7</th>
                    <th class="column-title">8</th>
                    <th class="column-title">9</th>
                    <th class="column-title">10</th>
                    <th class="column-title">11</th>
                    <th class="column-title">12</th>
                    <th class="column-title">13</th>
                    <th class="column-title">14</th>
                    <th class="column-title">15</th>
                    <th class="column-title">16</th>
                    <th class="column-title">17</th>
                    <th class="column-title">18</th>
                    <th class="column-title">19</th>
                    <th class="column-title">20</th>
                    <th class="column-title">21</th>
                    <th class="column-title">22</th>
                    <th class="column-title">23</th>
                    <th class="column-title">24</th>
                    <th class="column-title">25</th>
                    <th class="column-title">26</th>
                    <th class="column-title">27</th>
                    <th class="column-title">28</th>
                    <th class="column-title">29</th>
                    <th class="column-title" >30</th>
                    <th class="column-title" >31</th>
                 </tr>

                  </thead>

         <!-- 

             <tbody>

                   <tr class=''>
                    <th class="text-center">SHIFT(A+B)</th>

        <!--            <th class="text-center" rowspan="2"></th>
                    <th class="text-center" rowspan="2"></th>
                    <th class="text-center" rowspan="2"></th>
                    <th class="text-center" rowspan="2"></th>
                    <th class="text-center" rowspan="2"></th>
                    <th class="text-center" rowspan="2"></th>
                    <th class="text-center" rowspan="2"></th>
                    <th class="text-center" rowspan="2"></th>
                    <th class="text-center" rowspan="2"></th>
                    <th class="text-center" rowspan="2"></th>
                    <th class="text-center" rowspan="2"></th>
                    <th class="text-center" rowspan="2"></th>
                    <th class="text-center" rowspan="2"></th>
                    <th class="text-center" rowspan="2"></th>
                    <th class="text-center" rowspan="2"></th>
                    <th class="text-center" rowspan="2"></th>
                    <th class="text-center" rowspan="2"></th>
                    <th class="text-center" rowspan="2"></th>
                    <th class="text-center" rowspan="2"></th>
                    <th class="text-center" rowspan="2"></th>
                    <th class="text-center" rowspan="2"></th>
                    <th class="text-center" rowspan="2"></th>
                    <th class="text-center" rowspan="2"></th>
                    <th class="text-center" rowspan="2"></th>
                    <th class="text-center" rowspan="2"></th>
                    <th class="text-center" rowspan="2"></th>
                    <th class="text-center" rowspan="2"></th>
                    <th class="text-center" rowspan="2"></th>
                    <th class="text-center" rowspan="2"></th>
                    <th class="text-center" rowspan="2"></th>
                    <th class="text-center" rowspan="2"></th>
                </tr>
                <tr class=' '>  
                    <th class="column-title">AF OFF(KWP&KZK)</th>

                 </tr>
                 <tr class=' '> 
                    <th class="text-center">PDI OFF(KWP&KZK)</th>

                    <th class="text-center"></th>
                    <th class="text-center"></th>
                    <th class="text-center"></th>
                    <th class="text-center"></th>
                    <th class="text-center"></th>
                    <th class="text-center"></th>
                    <th class="text-center"></th>
                    <th class="text-center"></th>
                    <th class="text-center"></th>
                    <th class="text-center"></th>
                    <th class="text-center"></th>
                    <th class="text-center"></th>
                    <th class="text-center"></th>
                    <th class="text-center"></th>
                    <th class="text-center"></th>
                    <th class="text-center"></th>
                    <th class="text-center"></th>
                    <th class="text-center"></th>
                    <th class="text-center"></th>
                    <th class="text-center"></th>
                    <th class="text-center"></th>
                    <th class="text-center"></th>
                    <th class="text-center"></th>
                    <th class="text-center"></th>
                    <th class="text-center"></th>
                    <th class="text-center"></th>
                    <th class="text-center"></th>
                    <th class="text-center"></th>
                    <th class="text-center"></th>
                    <th class="text-center"></th>
                    <th class="text-center"></th>
                 </tr>

                 </tbody>  -->
             </table>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>        
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
          </div>
        <!-- /page content -->

    <!-- footer content -->




   </div>

    <!-- /footer content -->



    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="vendors/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script src="vendors/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- FastClick -->
    <script src="vendors/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js"></script>
    <!-- NProgress -->
    <script src="vendors/nprogress/nprogress.js"></script>
    <!-- Chart.js -->
    <script src="vendors/Chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <!-- gauge.js -->
    <script src="vendors/gauge.js/dist/gauge.min.js"></script>
    <!-- bootstrap-progressbar -->
    <script src="vendors/bootstrap-progressbar/bootstrap-progressbar.min.js"> 
    </script>
    <!-- iCheck -->
    <script src="vendors/iCheck/icheck.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Skycons -->
    <script src="vendors/skycons/skycons.js"></script>
    <!-- Flot -->
    <script src="vendors/Flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
    <script src="vendors/Flot/jquery.flot.pie.js"></script>
    <script src="vendors/Flot/jquery.flot.time.js"></script>
    <script src="vendors/Flot/jquery.flot.stack.js"></script>
    <script src="vendors/Flot/jquery.flot.resize.js"></script>
    <!-- Flot plugins -->
    <script src="vendors/flot.orderbars/js/jquery.flot.orderBars.js"> 
    </script>
    <script src="vendors/flot-spline/js/jquery.flot.spline.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendors/flot.curvedlines/curvedLines.js"></script>
    <!-- DateJS -->
    <script src="vendors/DateJS/build/date.js"></script>
    <!-- JQVMap -->
    <script src="vendors/jqvmap/dist/jquery.vmap.js"></script>
    <script src="vendors/jqvmap/dist/maps/jquery.vmap.world.js"></script>
    <script src="vendors/jqvmap/examples/js/jquery.vmap.sampledata.js"> 
    </script>
    <!-- bootstrap-daterangepicker -->
    <script src="vendors/moment/min/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendors/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"> 
    </script>

     <!-- Datatables -->
    <script src="vendors/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"> 
    </script>

    <script src="vendors/datatables.net-bs/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"> 
    </script>
    <script src="vendors/datatables.net-buttons
      /js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendors/datatables.net-buttons- 
     bs/js/buttons.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendors/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.flash.min.js"> 
    </script>
    <script src="vendors/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.html5.min.js"> 
    </script>
    <script src="vendors/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.print.min.js"> 
    </script>
    <script src="vendors/datatables.net/js/dataTables.editor.min.js"> 
    </script>
    <script src="vendors/datatables.net- 
       fixedheader/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendors/datatables.net- 
     keytable/js/dataTables.keyTable.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendors/datatables.net- 
     responsive/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendors/datatables.net-responsive- 
     bs/js/responsive.bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="vendors/datatables.net- 
     scroller/js/dataTables.scroller.min.js"></script>


    <!-- Custom Theme Scripts -->
    <script src="js/custom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/Production_monitor.js"></script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

But it is not working. Please help me.

Comment: Please show your HTML structure

Comment: Please add all of your code.

Comment: there is no id in your html

Comment: @Vel,Sorry, Didn't get you.

Comment: `$('#' + tid).remove();` there is no `id` attribute in your html.

Comment: @PavitraSharma Please post your complete html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#search").click(function() {
    var monthSelect = $("#selMonth").val();
    console.log(monthSelect);
    //var monthSelect = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    var tid = null;

    if(monthSelect == '4'|| monthSelect == '6'||   monthSelect == '9'||  monthSelect == '11') {
      $('#Production_monitor thead tr th').each(function (event) {
        if($(this).text() == '31'){
          $(this).remove();
        }
      });
    }

    if(monthSelect == '2') {
      $('#Production_monitor thead tr td').each(function (event) {
        tid = $(this).attr('id');

        if($(this).text() == '31'){
          $(this).remove();
        }

        if($(this).text() == '30'){
          $(this).remove();
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gnanavelr/71b2oh3r/8/)

Answer (score 0):

The following line will only remove a single element, most likely this element is in the table `thead`, and will not affect the entire column.

```
$('#' + tid).remove();
```

What you need to do is remove the 31st column from the whole table.

To do that, you will use `nth-child` to remove all `<td>` elements if they fall in the 31st place within their `<tr>` parent.

```
if($(this).text()=='31'){
        $('#Production_monitor tr td:nth-child(31)').remove();

}
```